# Allow outside G Suite domains to book rooms available in my domain

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I am trying to setup something in google that lets outside users to book rooms or resources available in my G Suite domain and thus making those resources as shared..

I was successfully able to update the resource calendar acl and add the new domain. But users from the other domain are not able to see any resource when trying to create an event in calendar.

Please suggest what might be wrong

Comment: Exactly what update did you make and what resource should the users be able to access? Could you please share a sample of the code you're working on?

Comment: we have conference rooms and meetings rooms where i have given access for users from other domain to add events.. but when a user from other domain logs into their calendar, they are not able to add events

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable "Resource booking permissions"

> Apps > Google Workspace > Settings for Calendar > General settings

2. Obtain access token via [Google's OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) for `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` scope
3. Add ACL via [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert) for outside user / domain with required permissions freeBusyReader / reader

> POST
> [https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendar_email@domain.com}/acl](https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%7Bcalendar_email@domain.com%7D/acl)
> Authorization: Bearer {access_token}

```
{
 "scope": {
 "type": "domain",
 "value": "externaldomain.com"
 },
 "role": "reader"
}
```

or

```
{
 "scope": {
 "type": "user",
 "value": "user1@externaldomain.com"
 },
 "role": "reader"
}
```

4. Now you should be able to add `calendar_email@domain.com` as Guest from calendar at externaldomain.com and also browse calendar events

Answer (score 1):

Have been able to solve this by adding the resource calendar to users from other domains where they can view the Free/Busy status

Users from other domains to include the resource / room id in the guest list when booking the room and this would solve the issue!